# Cut paste based on the length of data on particular cell

Tags: excel, vba

There is one column (Let say E) and I want to Iterate each row of the E column and want to check the length of data present in each row of E column, if length of data is greater than 255 then I wanted to cut the data and paste into F column but row number should be same as where I cut the data.

Example
E7 have data whose length is greater than 255, So I wanted to Cut the data from E7 and paste it into F7.
Similarly I wanted to do this for each record/Data present in E Column

Note: Column F will already have some data, we can overwrite the same while pasting

Comment: I think you need some macro (written in VBA) to do this useless stuff.

Comment: or you could enter the formula `=IF(LEN(E2)>255;E2;"")` in cell F2, and then copy this formula down to the end of your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I wanted to Cut the data from E7 and paste it into F7

Maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Set Rng = Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In Rng
If Len(cell.Value) > 255 Then cell.Cut cell.Offset(0, 1)
Next
End Sub
```

To highlight it :

```
Sub test2()
    Set Rng = Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each cell In Rng
    If Len(cell.Value) > 255 Then 
    cell.Cut cell.Offset(0, 1)
    cell.interior.color=vbyellow
    end if
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Karma , is there any way to highlight the text which are getting cut and paste,
I tried this code but it is highlighting each cell 
Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 0)).Interior.Color = 177

Comment: @user9910412, Please have a look on the other code on my post before.

Answer (score 0):

So based off your question I think your not actually trying to cut and paste the data you just want to identify the greater than 255 per row correct? Once you get what you need could you not just delete column F after?
You can paste below formulas into E7 and F7 to make your example real. Just copy the formulas down and you should be able to get something like what your looking for.
=REPT("a",RANDBETWEEN(1,300))  E7 formula
=IF( LEN(E1) > 255, E1, "")    F7 Formula